# How to make google form responses submit to bottom of spreadsheet and not ignore manually entered data in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a spreadsheet with responses from a form, but occasionally we manually enter responses into the spreadsheet that do not come in through the google form.  I would like these to remain in order with the form responses, but when a google form is submitted it inserts the next form response after the last form response and shifts the manually entered data on the spreadsheet down.

Is there a way I can get the manually entered data to be recognized when the form submits and always append the latest form response to the bottom of the spreadsheet?

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073445/google-form-linked-to-google-spreadsheet-order-of-responses) answer here but it doesnt work for me, it still ignores manual entries. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have automated data and manually entered data in the same range.

For instance, if you use an array formula on a sheet in in B:B, the array formula "owns" B:B. If you then enter manual data anywhere in B:B, you will "break" the array, all of your formula data will disappear and the original formula cell will show an error. Think of that error as Google Sheets' way of saying, "Looks like you decided that you want to use this range for manual data now instead of formula-produced data, so it appears your formula is now not what you want."

The same concept is true for form integration. A form does not "read" cell from your Google Sheet. It just outputs data to it. It's a one-way conversation, so to speak. As such, the form doesn't know what else you are doing on the form-data intake sheet. It only knows how to find the information that marks where it left off with the last submission; and then its instructions are to enter a new line below that point for the next new submission.

In other words, a form "owns" the sheet you integrate it with. And the form will do what it is programmed to do, regardless of whether you try to also "own" that sheet by typing into in manually.

**The simple solution**: *always use your form to enter data*.

If you say to yourself, "But using the form is more work than manual entry," it's time to rethink your form and your user experience, since forms are meant to make data entry *easier* than manual entry into the spreadsheet, not harder.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds plain, but i keyed in the timestamps columns of manually entered data to any earlier date and sorted the data by timestamp. the new data from the form would populate the bottom rows after

however new responses doesn't take your formats n formulas..maybe u have to export it for calculations etc

hope this helps